# Multi input model tensorflow with fixed data as input

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I am tring to implement the following architecture.
[image]

alpha and beta are fixed matrices, they are matrices I want to input on every forward pass. Meaning for every batch they should be the same My question is how to do that. I implemented the model and tried the following.

```py
batch_size = 64
epochs = 100
fitted = model.fit(
        [
            tr_x,
            alpha,
            beta,
        ],
        tr_y,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
    )
```

and got this error:
**ValueError: Data cardinality is ambigous:
X sizes: 14256, 742, 742
y sizes: 14256
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.**
then tried reshaping alpha and beta with the batch size in mind.
`np.repeat(alpha, batch_size)` but got same error. And when I tried np.repeat with tr_x.shape[0] it coudn't allocate enough memory.